# ROW_COUNT returns 0 after INSERT or UPDATE

Tags: mysql

I have a PHP project that uses Pear DB to deal with MySQL database. One of the functions inside of that project relies on a result of `SELECT ROW_COUNT()` to find out number of rows affected by certain SQL statement. On MySQL 5.1 `ROW_COUNT()` behaves as expected, whilst on 5.5 it always returns **0**.

I have also tried performing an insert through MySQL Workbench and executing `SELECT ROW_COUNT()` and it also returns 0. Although, doing same thing through MySQL cli, works fine!

Anybody stumbled upon this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour of `row_count()` has changed in MySQL 5.5. For more Information see the [MySQL RefMan for row_count()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//information-functions.html#function_row-count).

Comment: but for INSERTs it seems to behave as before, no?

Comment: Hmm yes indeed... the only other thing I can imagine is that Pear does some kind of transaction-stuff or so. Have you tried `affectedRows()` (from Pear)

Comment: So what is the answer? How do you get the number of affected rows upon an UPDATE? Could you give a simple example please?